# Dont vs Que: écouter de la musique

Tags: prépositions, pronoms-relatifs

When I'm saying

> J'écoute de la musique. La musique est belle.

But I can rewrite it using  dont,

> La musique dont j'écoute est belle.

Is it correct?

I'm not sure if this sentence is grammatically correct, but wouldn't this sentence use que instead?

> J'écoute la musique. La musique est belle
>
> La musique que j'écoute est belle

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*La musique dont j'écoute est belle* doesn't work. It must be *la musique que j'écoute…*

You are confused by the nature of *de* in the first sentence. *De* is not a preposition here but a partitive article (I'm listening to [some] music) so cannot lead to *dont*.

Here are sentences with the preposition *de* and their *dont* counterpart:

> Je te parle **de** la musique du XIX<sup>e</sup> siècle.
>
> La musique **dont** je te parle.
>
> J'écoute la musique **de** ce chanteur.
>
> Le chanteur **dont** j'écoute la musique.

But:

> J'écoute [**de**] la musique
>
> La musique **que** j'écoute.

Comment: Incidentally, to avoid confusion, I suppose you could also use *dont* if you mean "of which I listen to some but not all": « La musique dont je n'ai écouté que cinq minutes ... » Or some element of the music: « La musique dont je n'ai écouté que le commencement ... »

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes, and the similar *la musique dont j'écoute les percussions*

Comment: @LukeSawczak I might have written *la musique que je n'ai écoutée que cinq minutes ...* though.

Comment: Interesting. They could be disambiguated: "que j'ai écoutée pendant 5 minutes" vs. "dont j'ai écouté les premières 5 minutes", I guess?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Yes

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes *dont* can actually be translated into English as *which* (or *that*), which otherwise is the normal way of rendering *que* into English.

**Voilà le chat dont [not *que*] je suis jaloux.** Why *dont* here? Because the valency of the adjective *jaloux* is *de*. So, you have *être jaloux de*. Hence the sentence *Voilà le chat dont je suis jaloux* = *Here is the cat which / that I'm jealous of*.